# Basic mod_rewrite difficulties

Tags: mod-rewrite

My goal is to rewrite

```
http://domain.com/subdir/index.php?p=page-title
```

as

```
http://domain.com/subdir/page-title
```

The code below looks right, but I get a 404 Not Found?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/subdir/([^/.]+)/?$ /subdir/index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

Comment: does it redirect as expected?

Comment: @revo It's an internal rewrite, not a redirect, so that's hard to tell. That said, using `[R=temp]` in the flags is often a good way to see what the rule is doing.

Comment: @IMSoP however it has a hidden redirection I use word `redirect` for rewrite rules in general.

Comment: @revo In which case the answer is "no", otherwise this question wouldn't be here, surely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, remove the leading slash from your rule (assuming it's in `.htaccess` instead of `httpd.conf`)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^subdir/([^/.]+)/?$ /subdir/index.php?p=$1 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: I have no clue why it works without the `/` but thanks for your answer. Also thanks for the useful flags :)

Comment: @Midas, that's because within .htaccess `RewriteRule`'s path doesn't begin with a `/`.